# Solace Message Broker Message Spool Active Disk Partion

Tags: solace, solace-mq

What is meant by Active Disk Partition Usage: 100.00% when checking message-spool config? if this a concern how would I go about fixing it?

I have zero message spooled into Solace, but getting the above status, I also had issues provisioning new queues.

Is there a way to clear all system logs, i.e. command, event, debug and system? I understand that there is an archive policy for that, but I would like to have a clean state for my logs.

A full trace of message-spool is:
Config Status:                            Enabled (Primary)
Maximum Spool Usage:                      1500 MB
Using Internal Disk:                      Yes

Operational Status:                       AD-Active
Datapath Status:                          Up
Synchronization Status:                   Synced
Spool-Sync Status:                        Synced
  Last Failure Reason:                    N/A
  Last Failure Time:                      N/A
Max Message Count:                        240M
Message Count Utilization:                0.00%
Transaction Resource Utilization:         0.00%
Delivered Unacked Msgs Utilization:       0.00%
Spool Files Utilization:                  0.00%
Active Disk Partition Usage:              100.00%
Mate Disk Partition Usage:                -%
Next Message Id:                          222789873
Defragmentation Status:                   Idle
Number of delete in-progress:             0
Current Persistent Store Usage (MB)        0.0000       0.0000          0.0000
Number of Messages Currently Spooled            0            0               0

I am using System Software. SolOS-TR Version 7.2.2.34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring a software message broker disk space needs to be allocated to the device for spooling of messages. The Active Disk Partition Usage statistic refers to the amount of this allocated space that has currently been utilized.

If disk space is not partitioned for the spool, the disk space will be shared with the entire system. In this event, you would observe a high active disk partition with no messages spooled. To resolve the “Active Disk Partition Usage: 100.00%” you are experiencing, spool space should be provisioned to the broker. You can read more about Storage Configuration on Solace Brokers here (https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Configuring-Storage-Machine-Cloud.htm#).

Toi address your system logs question, clearing the logs is not an aspect that is supported by the router. Information stored to the system logs is timestamped and kept for troubleshooting purposes, as time progresses new information is appended to these files.